# accessing multiple objects in robot framework

Tags: python, frameworks, robotframework

Is there a way to explicitly access multiple objects of the same class in robot framework.
I have a class with a function to telnet to a host.
I want to connect to two different hosts and run different commands on those.
In my Robot Testcases file, I have

```
myclass.Login To Host     | host1  |  user  |  password

myclass.Run Cmd            |  ls

myclass.Login To Host    |  host2 | user  |  password

myclass.Run Cmd           |   ls -l
```

I see that the Run Cmd is executed on the first host (host1) in both the cases.
is there a way I can call functions on specific objects
Since this is part of my test case, I cant split them into two different test cases.

How can I call the second "Run Cmd" on the object thats created as a result of the Login To Host for host2 ?

Thanks
Bobby

Comment: could you share a little bit of the source code of your class so it is easier to answer you?

Comment: Here is my python code

Comment: Here is my Python Code
import pxssh <br>
import pexpect

class test():
  def __init__(self):
      self.conn = None
      
  def login_to_host(self, host, username='user', password='password'):

    ''' SSH to the box '''
    print 'logging in to %s' %host
    try:
        s = pxssh.pxssh()
        s.login (host, username, password)
        self.conn = s
    except pxssh.ExceptionPxssh, e:
        print "pxssh failed on login to %s." %host
        print str(e)
        
    print 'Successfully logged into %s' %host
    return s        

  run_cmd (self, cmd):
   self.conn.sendline(cmd)

Comment: @user3517560: a comment is not an appropriate place to put code. If the code in that comment clarifies your question, please put it in the question. It's impossible to read they way it is formatted in a comment.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. The Selenium2Library does this, for example.  If this is your class, you can do whatever you want. For example, have your login keyword return an identifier -- or let the test case supply one. Then, you could modify your run keyword to accept this identifier to know which connection to use.